Change the order of integration: $\int_0^2\int_y^{2y}xy dxdy$
I was presented on a class today the following integral and asked to calculate it and then try to change the order of integration: $$\int_0^2\int_y^{2y}xydxdy$$
As the integral is pretty simple I didn't have any trouble calculating it and easily got the result I = 6.
However I have no clue on how to change the order of integration. Any help would be welcomed.

What do you mean by "changing the order of integration?"

did you draw the region?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad "changing the order of integration" is not an ambiguous expression

I think I've got it :) Now I see that separating it into two integrals is the way to do it: I = $\int_0^2 \int_{1/2x}^x xydydx + \int_2^4 \int_{1/2x}^2 xydydx\$ Is it even possible to make it with only one integral?

It is not, except for the original $y$ integral in Cartesian coordinates. But switching to other coordinate systems like polar coordinates you would also get other 1 integral options.

@SineoftheTime i never said that it's an ambiguous expression

As you noted, changing the order of integration can be accomplished by splitting the region of integration $R$ into two parts.
The region $R$ can be determined by first noting that for each fixed $y \in [0,2]$, the region contains the interval $x \in [y, 2y]$.  So when $y = 0$, we have $x = 0$.  When $y = 2$, then $x \in [2,4]$.  Thus $R$ is a triangle whose vertices are at $(0,0)$, $(2,2)$, and $(4,2)$.
If we integrate with respect to $y$ first, then $R$ could be split into two sub-regions whose interiors are disjoint, and share the boundary $y \in [1,2]$:  specifically, the triangles with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(2,2)$; and the triangle with vertices $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, and $(4,2)$.  Then the integral over $R$ may be written
$$\int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=x/2}^x xy \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=2}^4 \int_{y=x/2}^2 xy \, dy \, dx.$$
The reason for this split is due to the vertex at $(2,2)$, and the fact that the sides of the triangle incident to this vertex comprise the piecewise function $$y(x) = \begin{cases} x, & 0 \le x \le 2 \\
2, & 2 < x \le 4. \end{cases}$$
Thus the upper limit of integration is specified for two separate cases.
One way we can "cheat" and write this as a non-piecewise function is to observe that on the interval $x \in [0,4]$, we can also write
$$y(x) = \min(x,2).$$
So we could also write the integral as
$$\int_{x=0}^4 \int_{y=x/2}^{\min(x,2)} xy \, dy \, dx.$$
While this seems like an improvement over splitting the region $R$, when one actually attempts to evaluate this expression, it needs to be split up anyway.
